# Ajuda com listas em PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade, porém estou com uma dificuldade em terminar um código.

Imagem da atividade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer em lista. Pois, acho que seria uma maneira eficaz de resolver esse exercício. Porém, precisaria calcular 1 por 1 dos números, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Código que estou tentando fazer:

```
L = []
P = []
C = int(input("Digite o código de 5 digitos: "))
P2 = int(input("Digite o peso (5 digitos): "))

L.append(C)
P.append(P2)


print(f"Codigo {L} e peso {P}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - O `while` controla a entrada entre 10000 e 30000.

2 - Converter a variavel para string para poder acessar os digitos separadamente.

3 - Colocar na vaiavel `resultado` cada digito sepadamente.

4 - Colocar na vaiavel `resultadoM` o produdo dos digitos pelo peso.

5 - Pegar o resto da divisao da `soma` por 7:

```
numero = int(input("Digite o código de 5 digitos: "))
while numero < 10000 or numero > 30000:
  numero = int(input("o numero deve ser entre 10000 e 30000: "))

resultado = []
resultadoM = []
digitoV = 0
soma = 0
for peso, valor in enumerate(str(numero), start = 2):
  resultado.append(int(valor))
  resultadoM.append(int(valor) * peso)
soma = sum(resultadoM)
digitoV = soma % 7

print('Numero ' + str(resultado))
print('Multiplicado: ' + str(resultadoM))
print('Soma: ' + str(soma))
print('Digito: ' + str(digitoV))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado estou estudando seu código para entender melhor.

Answer (score 0):

O enunciado solicita uma **FUNÇÃO** que retorne apenas o **DÍGITO VERIFICADOR** segundo determinadas regaras.

Um das formas que podemos montar a referida função é:

```
def digito_verificador(n):
    soma = 0
    o, p = str(n), list(range(2, 7))
    for i, j in zip(o, p):
        soma += int(i) * j
    return soma % 7


while not (num := input('Digite um número entre 10000 e 30000: ')).isdigit() \
        or (num := int(num)) < 10000 or num > 30000:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

print(digito_verificador(num))
```

A partir do momento que o código é inicializado, é capturado o valor digitado e, com ajuda do **Assignment Expression**, tratado e esgotado pela **[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)** é realizada três verificações consecutiva.

A primeira verificação avalia se a expressão atribuída à variável `num` **NÃO** é um dígito. A segunda, avalia se a conversão da variável `num` em inteiro é menor que `10000` e a terceira, avalia se tal conversão é maior que `30000`.

Caso uma dessa três verificações seja **True**, receberemos a mensgame **Valor INVÁLIDO!** e seremos novamente solicitado um valor.

Caso todas as três verificações seja **False** o laço `while` é encerrado, enviado o valor da variável `num` como parâmetro para a função **digito_verificador()**. Chegando lá, este valor será convertido em sting. Em seguida, o bloco for, com ajuda da função **zip()** percorrerá o interador "o" - que é o valor convertido em string - e a lista formada pelos pesos - que é gerada pelo range(2, 7).

Para cada interação do bloco for é incrementado o valor de "**int(i) * j**" gerando uma soma parcial.

Após ter realizado todas as interações cabíveis gerando a soma total, é calculado e exibido o resto da divisão entre soma e 7, ou seja, **soma % 7**.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

o carácter **" \ "** após o método **isdigit()** é utilizado para realizar uma mudança de linha sem sair do contexto da linha atual, ou seja, após o **" \ "** podemos continuar digitando o os comandos na linha imediatamente abaixo referente à mesma linha de comandos do while.

**Testando o código:**

Imagine que desejamos calcular o dígito verificador do valor **21853**. Pois, ao executar o código devemos digitar...

```
21853
```

...e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A partir desse momento será realizado os cálculos e receberemos como saída o valor:

```
5
```

Observe que o retorno da função é apenas o dígito verificador.